# How to check if given data exist or Not in mongodb and python

Tags: python, mongodb

I used below code.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
client=MongoClient()
db=client.mydb

if db.mycollections.find({"name": 'Chinna',"password":'chinna11'}).count() > 0:
    print("true")
else:
    print("false")
```

but it return below an error,

```
DeprecationWarning: count is deprecated. Use Collection.count_documents instead.
```

if anyone know, please help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're not interested in the documents and only what to count the matching ones, replace .find() with .count_documents():

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
client=MongoClient()
db=client.mydb

if db.mycollections.count_documents({"name": 'Chinna',"password":'chinna11'}) > 0:
    print("true")
else:
    print("false")
```